# Human date value with Morris.js Hover callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, morris.js

I'm trying to show a human readable date in my Morris.js Line Chart, but instead, it's showing the timestamp.  I've looked at the `hoverCallback` area, but am unsure of what to change:

**update_host_info.js.erb**

```
new Morris.Line({
  element: 'device_security_trend',
  data: $('#device_security_trend').data('security-trend'),
  smooth: false,
  ymax: 'auto[99]',
  xkey: 'created_at',
  ykeys: ['security_percentage'],
  labels: ['Security Percentage'],
  postUnits: '%',
  resize: true,
  hoverCallback: function(index, options, content) {
    return(content);
  }
});
```

**device_security_trend element**

```html
<div data-security-trend="[{"created_at":"2016-02-23T13:28:05.160-04:00", "security_percentage" :0},{"created_at":"2016-02-23T16:24:56.128-04:00","security_percentage":99},{"created_at":"2016-02-23T16:24:57.560-04:00","security_percentage":0}" id="device_security_trend" style="width: 100%; position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" class="selected"><div class="morris-hover-row-label">2016-02-23T13:28:05.160-04:00</div><div class="morris-hover-point" style="color: #689bc3">
  Security Percentage:
  0%
</div></div>
```

Right, now this is what my hover tooltip looks like:

[image]

Instead, I'd like the date/time to be more readable, something like:

`4/19/2016 - 9:30am`

Comment: You'll have to show us the contents of `#device_security_trend` element.

Comment: There you go @Uzbekjon

Comment: @Uzbekjon well, you got me thinking about just changing the date format in the first place... so, what's what I did in a helper.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just changing how the Date was being fed into Morris.js through a helper method that converts the time to something human readable.